# How to exit a batch function?

Tags: batch-file

So I wanted to do something like this:

```
@echo off
echo Before
call :test
echo After
pause

:test
echo I'm in test!
:end

echo I shouldn't be here...
```

Such that it would call test after saying `Before` and before saying `After`. However, it keeps just saying `I shouldn't be here` before saying `After`! Now, it's not necessarily a problem in this example, but when I have a whole bunch of functions, it can be quite an issue. Can anyone please help me? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Batch has no concept of "sections", "functions", "procedures" or "paragraphs". A label is simply a reference point. Execution does not stop when a label is reached, it simply continues through, line by line, until it reaches end-of-file, a **CALL** , a **GOTO** or an **EXIT**. This is why you get the message you mention - and why the `I'm in test!` and the "rogue" message appear after your `pause` (which you wouldn't see if you are executing the batch by "click"ing it)

You need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

You can use `goto :eof` to terminate a subroutine (reaching end-of-file terminates the routine and returns to the statement after the `call`) OR you can use `exit` or `exit /b [n]` as explained in the documentation (se `exit /?` from the prompt.

The downside of using `exit` is that it will terminate the `cmd` instance if executed when the routine hasn't been `call`ed - ie. it's part of the main routine - consequently, `goto :eof` is more popular.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended each function, or label as you call it ;) , with `goto :eof` and it works wonders! :D

Comment: Hmm - terminology. The *function*, *procedure*, *subprocedure*, *routine* or *subroutine* (in batch, these terms are equivalent) known as ":test" or "test" is the sequence of instructions that starts at the *label* `:test`

Comment: I see... As someone who has always done OOP, I find it really awkward to use `goto :some label`, which a lot of good batch scripters use (...and what I used to use), instead of `call :some label`. Now that I can call these labels without trouble, it's much more comfortable for me to write batch and much less confusing to debug. :P